# Python: How to reverse an objects string function in python

Tags: python, string

For example, I have a class Wall (doesnt have an **init**)

if `a = Wall()`

and `str(a)` outputs: `'#'`

if i have a string containing '####'

how can i turn that string into a list, that has the name of the class object like this:
`[Wall(), Wall(), Wall(), Wall()]`

Comment: Are there other object types you want to create or just `Wall` objects?

Comment: What if the input string is 'a#b#c'?

Comment: Do you have an exhaustive `list` of strings corresponding to classes? With the limited examples you give, there are just too many possible options, many of which won't work for your use case. We need more details, more evidence of effort, and a [MCVE] that's more than just one fairly unclear example.

Comment: *"...that has the name of the class object"*: what does that mean? Do you mean the list elements should be strings having that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a filtering clause:

```
walls = [Wall() for char in string
         if char == '#']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an explicit mapping dictionary that tells what each of the characters in the string is supposed to mean.

```
wall = object()

mapping = {
    "#": wall
}

string = '####'

result = [mapping[ch] for ch in string]
```

Comment: I like this mapping answer, it's more flexible.

Comment: Won't all the objects be the same object?

Comment: @PeterWood they will, but the question was too poorly phrased for me to know whether that is desired behaviour or not.

Comment: You should ask for clarification and help new users make better questions.